# How to show that there's a continuous function separating convex sets of Radon measures?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, convex-analysis, ergodic-theory

First, the setup: $X$ is a compact set. By Riesz's representation theorem $C(X)^*=${all Radon measures on $X$}. $K$ is a convex, closed (weak-* sense) set of probability measures. $m$ is a probability measure out of $K$.
In a paper I read, the author uses the fact that there's a continuous function $g$ s.t. $\int gdm>sup_{\mu \in K}\{\int gd\mu\}$

So far I was able to show that $\exists \psi\in C(X)^{**}$ s.t. $\psi(m)>sup_{\mu \in K}\{\psi(\mu)\}$

And also that the unit ball of $C(X)$ is dense in the weak-* topology in the unit ball of $C(X)^{**}$, meaning that $\exists \{g_n\}\subset B(C(X))$ s.t. $g_n\overset{w-*}{\longrightarrow} \psi$, where the canonical embedding is $g_n(\mu)=\int g_n d\mu$.

Making the final step of showing some continuous function actually fulfills the desired inequality, has been unsuccessful for me so far. Neither could I find any book that show a similar claim.

Any help would be appreciated, especially a simple quick solution that I missed.

Comment: Would you please include a citation/reference for the mentioned paper?

Comment: Sure: http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-46/3/471.full.pdf

Comment: It's in the beginging of the thorem that characterizes the set of tangent functionals to the topological pressure at a 'point' $f$

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this result is true, you need that $K$ is closed w.r.t. the weak-* topology.

The following is a counterexample: Take $X = [0,1]$ and $m$ the Lebesgue measure. $K$ is the closed convex hull of the Dirac measures. Then, $m \not\in K$ (see below) but you cannot separate $m$ from $K$ with a continuous function.

It remains to show $m \not\in K$.
It is easy to see that
\begin{equation*}
 L = \Big\{ \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i \, \delta_{x_i} \text{ for some } n, x_i, 0 \le \alpha_i, \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i = 1\Big\}.
\end{equation*}
is the convex hull of the Dirac measures.
Then, $K$ is the closure of $L$.
Moreover, it is easy to see that the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$ has distance $2$ from all measures in $L$, hence it does not belong to $K$.

Note, however, that $\lambda$ belongs to the weak-* closure of $K$ and this is the reason why you cannot separate it from $K$.

**In response to the edit:** If $K$ is weak-* closed,
this separation is a standard result. The mentioned paper already includes a reference to Dunford/Schwartz. It can also be found in other books, see also [Separation in dual space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214655/separation-in-dual-space).

Comment: I believe this specific counter example doesn't prove your claim, since if I'm not mistaken, the lebesgue measure $\lambda=lim\frac{1}{n} \overset{n-1}{\underset{k=0}{\Sigma}} \delta_{\frac{k}{n}}$ in the weak sense.

Comment: I have expanded my answer. Note that your sequence only converges in the weak-* topology, but not in the weak or the norm topology.

Comment: Okay, sorry, I meant wothout specifying that K is closed in weak-* sense, then it eould be compact w.r.t to that topology. I'll specify it. Thanks

Comment: But this totally changes the question...

Comment: Sorry then, for some reason it seemed like default to me.