# Is an lsc sublinear function $X^* \rightarrow (-\infty, \infty]$ always a support function for some closed non-empty $C \subset X$?

Tags: functional-analysis, convex-analysis

I can't seem to find any resources on this, even though it seems like an obvious question to ask. The separation theorem implies that, if we have an lsc sublinear function $\phi : X^* \rightarrow (-\infty, \infty]$, and it is equal to a support function $\mathrm{supp}_C$, then $C$ must be the set:
$$C = \bigcap\limits_{f \in X^*} f^{-1}(-\infty, \phi(f)].$$
Moreover, we can easily see that, if we define $C$ as above, then $\mathrm{supp}_C \le \phi$.

Certainly $C$ is closed and convex. I can't seem to prove even that $C$ is non-empty, but I have a suspicion that this may be most of the battle. I also suspect that this is conditional on $X$ being reflexive. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sublinear is not enough: a sublinear function may fail homogeneity. Also, lower semicontinuous in what topology? Please state precisely the statement you ask about, with hypotheses and expected conclusion. Also, something to consider: if $X$ is not reflexive, take $z\in X^{**}\setminus X$ and let $\phi(f) = |f(z)|$ for $f\in X^*$.

Comment: I was under the impression that positive homogeneity was a property of sublinearity (Wikipedia seems to agree). Just assume that $\phi$ is positive-homogeneous. As for being lsc, I was thinking norm, and hence weakly lsc, but I now think it ought to be refined further to being weak$^*$ lsc because (correct me if I'm wrong here) support functions are automatically weak$^*$ lsc. I just want a characterisation of support functions, that's all. One that does not rely on knowing the set in question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\phi:X^*\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ be a sublinear weak* lsc functional. If we assume $\phi$ is proper (meaning $\phi\not\equiv \infty$ or equivalently its essential domain is non-empty) then for some $x^*$ in its essential domain $\phi(x^*)<\infty$. The following two subsets $\{(x^*,\phi (x^*)-1)\}$ (a weak* compact subset) and  $\mathbb{epi}\phi:=\{(f,\beta)\in X^*\times\mathbb{R};\ \phi(f)\leq\beta\}$ (a weak* closed subset) are convex and disjoint so by a [separation theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/214655/separation-in-dual-space) they can be separated by a weak*-continuous linear functional $(x,\lambda)\in X\times\mathbb{R}$ hence

$$x^*(x)+\lambda\cdot(\phi(x^*)-1)\leq f(x)+\lambda\cdot\beta$$

for any $(f,\beta)\in\mathbb{epi}\phi$. Since $\beta$ in not bounded above $\lambda$  must be non-negative, and for $\beta=\phi(f)$ we get

$$x^*(x)+\lambda\cdot(\phi(x^*)-1)\leq f(x)+\lambda \phi(f)$$

for any $f\in \mathbb{dom}\phi$. Of course the above inequality holds even for $f\notin \mathbb{dom}\phi$ since in that case the right side of the inequality is $\infty$. Since $x(\cdot)+\lambda \phi(\cdot):X^*\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is sublinear and bounded below (by the constant $x^*(x)+\lambda\cdot(\phi(x^*)-1)$) it must be non-negative (exercise) hence

$$f(-\frac{1}{\lambda}x)\leq\phi(f) \ \forall f\in X^*$$

so we may conclude that $-\frac{1}{\lambda}x\in C$ and $C\not=\emptyset$.

A few remarks:

1. We assumed that $\phi$ is proper. If it isn't then  $C=X$ hence $C\not = \emptyset$.
2. Since you mentioned reflexivity, I'll add that in the case that $X$
   is reflexive the weak-* and norm topologies coincide so you may
   consider the latter instead if the former.
3. You also claimed that if $\phi$  is a support function on some set, this set must be $C$ which is false as can be easily seen by the example
   $\phi:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined by
   $\phi(x):=\max\{x,-x\}$ (try to find $C$ in this case).
4. The separation theorem used above states that in a locally convex
   space (in particular a dual space), a compact subset and a closed subset which are convex and disjoint can be (strongly) separated by a continuous linear functional.
5. One can replace the space $(X^*,\sigma(X^*,X))$ above with any locally convex space.

Comment: In point 3, I'm not sure I understand your example. I'm guessing $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is used to represent $f_x : y \mapsto xy$? Because then, when $x > 0$, we have $f_x^{-1}(-\infty, \phi(f_x)] = x^{-1}(-\infty, x] = (-\infty, 1]$, and similarly, when $x < 0$, then $f_x^{-1}(-\infty, \phi(f_x)] = x^{-1}(-\infty, -x] = [-1, \infty)$ (and in the case $x = 0$, the set is $\mathbb{R}$). So, the intersection is $C = [-1, 1]$, for which indeed the support function is $f_x \mapsto |x|$. It is late, so I might have missed something.

Comment: C is indeed the interval you mentioned, and this is why this example contradicts your claim: By definition, $f$ is the support function of the finite set $\{-1,1\}$ which is not $C$. Of course $f$ is also the support funciton of $C$, but of other sets as well.

Comment: Right; I slightly misspoke. I should have said, the set could be chosen to be the given set. Obviously the set can differ up to the same closed convex hull. After all, I am looking to show that all such functions are support functions of some set.